# Documentation: both data and initial for formset

Tags: django, django-forms

**Django 1.10.**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#can-order
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete

The examples at both of the abovementioned links are as follows:

```
>>> data = {
...     'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '3',
...     'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '2',
...     'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
...     'form-0-title': 'Article #1',
...     'form-0-pub_date': '2008-05-10',
...     'form-0-DELETE': 'on',
...     'form-1-title': 'Article #2',
...     'form-1-pub_date': '2008-05-11',
...     'form-1-DELETE': '',
...     'form-2-title': '',
...     'form-2-pub_date': '',
...     'form-2-DELETE': '',
... }

>>> formset = ArticleFormSet(data, initial=[
...     {'title': 'Article #1', 'pub_date': datetime.date(2008, 5, 10)},
...     {'title': 'Article #2', 'pub_date': datetime.date(2008, 5, 11)},
... ])
```

What troubles me: why should we need initial data here? It overburdens the documentation as we don't use the initial data in the example. The only case when we need both data and initial is when we use has_changed().

I'm a newbie. Maybe I don't understand that deep.

How do you think, maybe I should draw the attention of the community at Djangoproject to this problem?

Comment: Yes, I agree that `initial` could be removed from those examples. It would be great if you [open a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/) and even better if you have a go at writing a patch for the docs. See [the contributing guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/internals/contributing/) for more info.

Comment: I see you opened a [ticket 27280](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27280). After reading Tim's comment, I think I've changed my mind. As you say, the code will still work without `initial`, but if you leave it out it might cause confusion if you try to use `has_changed` later. Therefore it's good practice to use `initial` in the GET (e.g. `formset = ArticleFormSet(data=None, initial=initial)`) and POST (e.g. `formset = ArticleFormSet(data=request.POST, initial=initial)`) parts of a view.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to open a Django ticket anyway. The Django community really cares about good documentation, and new users can often spot issues that experienced users might not notice.